# Meaning of row space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I used to think of the row space of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ as the column space of $A^T$, and therefore the row vectors are the images of the standard dual basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ under $A^T$.

But it seems that we can have an interpretation of the row space without introducing the dual space.

I think, but am not sure, that the row spaces are those vectors which are 1-1 mapped to vectors in the column space.

Is this correct?

Comment: One interpretation of the row space is the space perpendicular to the kernel of the matrix.

Comment: @LeonSot But if we don't have inner product, how to define perpendicular?

Comment: This interpretation is really only valid over $\mathbb{R}$ but some of the intuition does carry over to other fields.

Answer (score 7):

The column space of a matrix $ A $ is the set of all vectors $ y $ such there $ y $ is a linear combination of the columns of $ A $.  In other words, it is the set of all vectors $ y $ such that there is a vector $ x $ with $ A x = y $.

What does that mean?  It means that it is the set of all vector for which $ A x = y $ has a solution.  If you ask the question "for what vectors $ y $ does $ A x = y $ have a solution?" the answer is "for all vectors in the columns space".

If you think of the rows of matrix $ A $ as vectors, then the row space is the set of all vectors that are linear combinations of the rows.  In other words, it is the set of all vectors $ y $ such that $ A^T x = y $ for some vector $ x $.

How are they related?  You can prove that if $ y $ is in the column space of $ A $, then any solution to $ A x = y $ can be written as $ x = x_r + x_n $, where $ x_r $ is in the row space of $ A $ and $ x_n $ is in the null space ($ A x_n = 0 $).

Answer (score 1):

The [row space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces#Row_space)  of an m-by-n matrix is the linear subspace generated by *row vectors* of the matrix.

> that the row spaces are those vectors which are 1-1 mapped to vectors in the column space.

<s>I cannot make sense of this statement. However,</s>

one has the theorem that the row space of $A$ and the column space of $A$ are of the same dimension. Also, note that if two vector spaces are of the same finite dimension, they are isomorphic.

Comment: $A $ maps each element of the row space to a unique element of the column space.

Comment: @Ian How to prove this?

Comment: @velutluna The $i$th component of the vector $Ax$ is the dot product of the $i$th row of $A$ with $x$. Thus if $Ax=0$ then $x$ is orthogonal to each row of $A$ and therefore to the entire row space of $A$. And the converse is true. So the null space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$. It should not be hard to see that restricting $A$ to the orthogonal complement of its null space results in an injective map.